# Mocking WSResponse on POST call returns null

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to mock a post call but it returns null on call `wsrequest.post("{}")`. I've mocked all calls until response and still no working:

```
val mockWS = mock(classOf[AhcWSClient])
val mockRequest = mock(classOf[WSRequest])
val mockResponse = mock(classOf[WSResponse])
when(mockResponse.body).thenReturn("{}")
when(mockRequest.withRequestTimeout(10.seconds)).thenReturn(mockRequest)
when(mockRequest.post("{}")).thenReturn(Future { mockResponse })
when(mockWS.url(anyString())).thenReturn(mockRequest)
```

Anyone have an idea why `post` is not being mocked? The mock on `get` works fine.

Here is what i'm trying to test:

```
val a = ws.url(s"$URL/groups")
val b = a
val c = b.post("{}")
```

On call to obtain `WSResponse`, it returns null (`val c ...`)

Comment: Are you using the Play WSClient?

Comment: @Tyler Yes, i do!